# Maven, dependencies between projects

Tags: maven, dependencies

I hace rather silly problem. I've tried to google and read other stackoverflow questions and unfortunately failed to get the idea.
Here is a structure of my projects:

```
-MapreduceProject (mapreduce jobs)
-UtilsProject (common stuff, usual project util garbage)
-WebAppProject (servlets, jsp for Tomcat)
```

**MapreduceProject** and **WebAppProject** both use **UtilsProject** 
What is the best way to specify it? I don't want to use aggregate. I prefer to see UtilsProject as separate jar.

I've added UtilsProject to Mapreduce and WebApp project as dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.super.mr</groupId>
    <artifactId>UtilsProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

It looks like rather silly and it doesn't work
I did run **mvn install** for *UtilsProject*. I did check that it's jar is *really in my local repo*.
But I can't compile other projects. I get an error:

Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project my.super.mr:WebAppProject:war
:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find my.super.mr:UtilsProject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://download.java.net/maven/2 was cached in the local reposit
ory, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of java.net2 has elapsed or updates are forced

Please help me to understand how to resolve it.

Comment: It looks ok. Are you specifying the correct `groupId`?

Comment: Omg, yes, I've missed one letter in <dependency> <groupId>... It works now

Comment: add it as an answer, so this can be marked as resolved :)

Comment: @eis, I've marked maba comment is useful, I don't see button to mark his comment as answer

Comment: I created an answer with my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your `<groupId/>` is correct. There could be a typo.